# C# Convert Byte Array with nulls to string

Tags: c#, string, encode

All,

I have a question about converting byte arrays with nulls to C# string.
Here is an example of my byte array that I would like to convert to string.
I expect to get a string with value SHKV

```
[0]: 83
[1]: 0
[2]: 72
[3]: 0
[4]: 75
[5]: 0
[6]: 86
[7]: 0
```

How can I do it in C# ?

Thanks,
MK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really need to know the original encoding in order to convert it successfully.

I suspect that in this case the encoding is probably [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2), which you can convert as follows:

```
byte[] yourByteArray = new byte[] { 83, 0, 72, 0, 75, 0, 86, 0 };

string yourString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(yourByteArray));

Console.WriteLine(yourString);    // SHKV
```

Answer (score 3):

That looks like little-endian UTF-16, so:

```
string s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you guaranteed to always see this encoding of the strings (char, null, char, null, etc.)? If so, you can simply use the Unicode string encoder to decode it:

```
    Byte[] contents = new Byte[] {83, 0, 72, 0, 75, 0, 86, 0};
    Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(contents));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ASCII bytes, you can do use LINQ:

```
new string(bytes.Where(b => b != 0).Select(b => (char)b).ToArray());
```

However, I suspect that you're trying to hack away Unicode data.

**DON'T**.

Instead, use the [`Encoding` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(bytes.Where(i => i != 0).ToArray());
```

Also you can use `UnicodeEncoding`, `UTF32Encoding`, `UTF7Encoding` or `UTF8Encoding`

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq syntax:

```
var chars = 
    from b in byteArray
    where b != 0
    select (char) b;

string result = new String(chars.ToArray());
```

Though you are better off selecting the right encoding instead, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

byte[] b = new byte[]{83,0,72,0,75,0,86,0};

System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(b);